# Fix eclipse project setup

Tags: eclipse

`import java.util.*;` is not recognized by eclipse, shows red alert. All java API's are not recognized.

Here is what happened. java 7 got installed to my system automatically. From that incident, it is behaving like this. I have uninstalled Java 7. I don't use eclipse to build or run.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is the project setup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `classpath` in *eclipse* and make sure it has a reference to `jre` library. If not, add it.

**UPDATE:**

Right-click on an error. Click on `Quick Fix` and search for the suggestion of importing a project or library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question with my project setup. Even though I have jre library. I face this issue. Please help.

Comment: @Vanathi try restarting eclipse?

Comment: @Vanathi Good. Sometimes eclipse crashes and needs a restart :)

Comment: Again, it failed in few seconds :(

Comment: @Vanathi go to your jre directory (C:\program files\java\jre6 and make sure it contains all the required jars